# Can I build multiple projects with dotnet build?

Tags: .net-core

Can I somehow build multiple projects with one root `project.json` file (or otherwise)? For example, one library, one test project, and one command line? If so, how?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I have these three projects and I want to build them all with one build command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be one year late in answering, but may be it is still useful for somebody who lands here after this.

dotnet build no longer uses project.json, instead uses *.csproj. And dotnet build can now take a directory name as an argument, and uses the *.csproj within that directory for the build. This being the case, the easiest way to build from a top-level-directory goes like this:

Assuming the structure of your projects is:

```
src
  |
  + -- proj1
  |
  + -- proj2
  |
  + -- proj3
  |
  .
  .
```

Just go to the top-level directory (`src` in this case), and type this:

```
Get-ChildItem -exclude ".vscode" | %{Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta "Building $_..."; dotnet build $_;}
```

I normally use PowerShell within VSCode, and hence you see the `-exclude ".vscode"` and PowerShell commands `Get-ChildItem` (aliased also as simply '`dir`') and `Write-Host`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Won't that end up building dependent projects multiple times? Like if proj1 depends on proj2, the latter will be built both when the script loops to proj1 and proj2?

Answer (score 2):

If all of your projects are stored in a structure like this :

```
<root>/src/Project1
<root>/src/Project2
```

then you can use a single command with a globbing pattern to build all of the projects at once:

```
dotnet build src/**/project.json
```

From what I am aware of, you'll still need individual project.json files for each project though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root of your solutions and run the following PowerShell (only for .NET Core projects)

```bsh
$baseDir = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
Write-Host ("Scanning *.sln files in " + $baseDir)
$solutionPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $baseDir -Include *.sln -Recurse
Write-Host ("Total found: " + $solutionPaths.Count)
foreach ($solutionPath in $solutionPaths) {  
    Write-Host ("Building => " + $solutionPath)
    dotnet build $solutionPath
}
```